# solving differential equation with step function

Tags: python, scipy, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to solve this differential equation as part of my assignment. I am not able to understand on how can i put the condition for u in the code. In the code shown below, i arbitrarily provided

```
u = 5. 


2dx(t)dt=−x(t)+u(t)

5dy(t)dt=−y(t)+x(t)

u=2S(t−5)

x(0)=0

y(0)=0
```

`where S(t−5) is a step function that changes from zero to one at t=5. When it is multiplied by two, it changes from zero to two at that same time, t=5`.

```
def model(x,t,u):
    dxdt = (-x+u)/2
    return dxdt

def model2(y,x,t):
    dydt = -(y+x)/5
    return dydt

x0 = 0
y0 = 0
u = 5
t = np.linspace(0,40)


x = odeint(model,x0,t,args=(u,))
y = odeint(model2,y0,t,args=(u,))
plt.plot(t,x,'r-')
plt.plot(t,y,'b*')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Feel free to accept any of the answers (green hook below the up and down vote button). This helps us with our reputation. Please give a little feedback...

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the SciPy Library very well, but regarding the [example in the documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) I would try something like this:

```
def model(x, t, K, PT)
    """
    The model consists of the state x in R^2, the time in R and the two
    parameters K and PT regarding the input u as step function, where K
    is the infimum of u and PT is the delay of the step.
    """
    x1, x2 = x   # Split the state into two variables

    u = K if t>=PT else 0    # This is the system input

    # Here comes the differential equation in vectorized form
    dx = [(-x1 + u)/2,
          (-x2 + x1)/5]
    return dx

x0 = [0, 0]
K  = 2
PT = 5
t = np.linspace(0,40)

x = odeint(model, x0, t, args=(K, PT))
plt.plot(t, x[:, 0], 'r-')
plt.plot(t, x[:, 1], 'b*')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here, and the step function is only a small part of it.  You can define a step function with a simple `lambda` and then simply capture it from the outer scope without even passing it to your function.  Because sometimes that won't be the case, we'll be explicit and pass it. 
Your next problem is the order of arguments in the function to integrate. As per the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) (y,t,...).  Ie, First the function, then the time vector, then the other `args` arguments.  So for the first part we get:

```
u = lambda t : 2 if t>5 else 0

def model(x,t,u):
    dxdt = (-x+u(t))/2
    return dxdt

x0 = 0
y0 = 0
t = np.linspace(0,40)


x = odeint(model,x0,t,args=(u,))
```

Moving to the next part, the trouble is, you can't feed `x` as an arg to y because it's a vector of values for `x(t)` for particular times and so `y+x` doesn't make sense in the function as you wrote it. You can follow your intuition from math class if you pass an x function instead of the x values.  Doing so requires that you interpolate the x values using the specific time values you are interested in (which scipy can handle, no problem):

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
xfunc = interp1d(t.flatten(),x.flatten(),fill_value="extrapolate") 
#flatten cuz the shape is off , extrapolate because odeint will go out of bounds
def model2(y,t,x):
    dydt = -(y+x(t))/5
    return dydt
y = odeint(model2,y0,t,args=(xfunc,))
```

Then you get:

[image]

@Sven's answer is more idiomatic for vector programming like scipy/numpy.  But I hope my answer provides a clearer path from what you know already to a working solution.

Comment: Solving the equations one by one seems a little bit odd.

Comment: @SvenKrüger, in general, yea.  But since y is strictly dependent on x here, you can decouple.  If a pattern shows up like that in a real-life multidimensional problem, it would probably be worth exploiting. But the programming paradigm is less neat than a single differentiation matrix.  Which is preferable from an educational perspective? Idk, I'm glad we both answered.

Comment: In a symbolic solution I kind of like this pattern, but in a numeric solution I think it is problematic to rely on a interpolated time series - rounding errors all I see.